# Can't install tornado

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, tornado, easy-install

**I am setting up tensorflow and i got this output:**

```
ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
```

so i am doing

```
sudo easy_install tornado
```

and i got as output:

```
earching for tornado
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/tornado/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/tornado/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
Couldn't find index page for 'tornado' (maybe misspelled?)
Scanning index of all packages (this may take a while)
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Download error on https://pypi.python.org/simple/: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:590) -- Some packages may not be found!
No local packages or download links found for tornado
error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('tornado')
```

**what should i do?**
thanks 
francesco

ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.

Comment: any particular reason why you're using `easy_install` instead of `pip`?

Comment: tryed also with this one but i got as output: ERROR: unknown command "tornado"

Comment: do `pip install tornado` instead of `pip tornado`

Comment: got me those errors: ERROR: matplotlib 1.3.1 requires nose, which is not installed.
Installing collected packages: singledispatch, backports-abc, tornado
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/singledispatch.py'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are running the command behind a proxy or a firewall. If this is the case, then you need to set the corresponding environment variables:

```
set http_proxy="username:password@host:port"
set https_proxy="username:password@host:port"
```

Otherwise, you can install `tornado` using `pip` by running (if you are not behind a proxy, then ignore `--proxy`):

```
pip --proxy http://user:password@proxy-host:port install tornado
```

**EDIT**: I would suggest to run

```
sudo -H pip install --ignore-installed matplotlib
```

in order to install the required packages and ignore the current version.

Comment: semms worked: Successfully installed backports.functools-lru-cache-1.5 cycler-0.10.0 kiwisolver-1.1.0 matplotlib-2.2.4 numpy-1.16.3 pyparsing-2.4.0 python-dateutil-2.8.0 pytz-2019.1 setuptools-41.0.1 six-1.12.0 subprocess32-3.5.3